# Is it possible to use indices and normals together?

Tags: opengl, rust

I have problems with lighting in OpenGL. When I don't use indices, shadows look as they should:

```
let cube: [f32; 324] = [
    //positions        //normals         //color
    -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  0.0,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  0.0,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    -0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  0.0,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    
    -0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    -0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    -0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    
    -0.5,  0.5,  0.5, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    -0.5,  0.5, -0.5, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    -0.5, -0.5,  0.5, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    -0.5,  0.5,  0.5, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    
     0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    
    -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    -0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    
    -0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    -0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    -0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
];
```

[image: Without indices]

When I use indices, I don't get the same result:

```
let cube: [f32; 72] = [
    //positions        //normals         //colors
    -0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
     0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
     0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0,

    -0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    -0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
     0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
     0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
];

let cube_indices: [i32; 36] = [
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0,
    4, 5, 6,
    6, 7, 4,
    4, 0, 3,
    3, 7, 4,
    5, 1, 2,
    2, 6, 5,
    0, 1, 5,
    5, 4, 0,
    3, 2, 6,
    6, 7, 3,
];
```

[image: With indices]

My shaders are from the "Learn OpenGL" tutorial:

- [vertex shader](https://github.com/JoeyDeVries/LearnOpenGL/blob/master/src/2.lighting/2.1.basic_lighting_diffuse/2.1.basic_lighting.vs)
- [fragment shader](https://github.com/JoeyDeVries/LearnOpenGL/blob/master/src/2.lighting/2.1.basic_lighting_diffuse/2.1.basic_lighting.fs)

Comment: Yes of course. The vertex coordinate and the normal vector form a tuple with 6 components (x, y, z, nx, ny, nz). There are no vertices where this 6 components are equal, thus you cannot share vertices by indices. Indices can only be use for "smooth" meshes, where all the vertex attributes are the same for the adjacent primitives (e.g a sphere).

Comment: If it is solved, **accept an answer**. Do not edit your question to say the words "solved".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course. The vertex coordinate and the normal vector form a tuple with 6 components (x, y, z, nx, ny, nz). There are no vertices where this 6 components are equal and are used on different sides of the cube, thus you cannot share vertices by indices among cube sides. Indices can only be use for "smooth" meshes, where all the vertex attributes are the same for the adjacent primitives (e.g a sphere).

Anyway you can create 4 vertex tuples for each side of the cube:

```
let cube: [f32; 216] = [
    //positions        //normals         //color
    -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  0.0,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    -0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  0.0,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    
    -0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    -0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    
    -0.5,  0.5,  0.5, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    -0.5,  0.5, -0.5, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    -0.5, -0.5,  0.5, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    
     0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    
    -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    -0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     
    -0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    -0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
];
```

And specify 6 indices (2 triangles) for each side of the cube:

```
let cube_indices: [i32; 36] = [
     0,  1,  2,     0,  2,  3,
     4,  5,  6,     4,  6,  7,
     8,  9, 10,     8, 10, 11,
    12, 13, 14,    12, 14, 15,
    16, 17, 18,    16, 18, 19,
    20, 12, 22,    20, 22, 23,
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible. But every time you use the same index, you get the same normal. If you don't want the same normal, you must use a different index.

Comment: In the array of vertices there is not any vertex which has the same coordinate and normal vector, thus the only  possibility would be to use 1 separate index for each vertex. That doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: @Rabbid76 If you never have two of the same vertex, then using indexed rendering is a waste of time. You do duplicate a few vertices though. Each side has 4 vertices, and 2 of them are used once, and 2 of them are used twice.

Comment: I see your point. I recommend to add an example to the answer.